# Using filter_var with parameters

Tags: php

I am trying check if variable is integer number and if she is in diapason: 2-15.

I am trying make this using `filter_var()` function. but I dont understood how correct use `min_range` and `max_range` parameters.

this not works, where I am wrong?

```
$c = 48;

if ( filter_var($c, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT , array("min_range"=>2,"max_range"=>15)) === false ) {
    echo "bad";
}
```

Comment: Explain what doesn't work please.

Comment: not prints "bad" in this case

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The min_range and max_range values have to be one level, deeper:

```
// for filters that accept options, use this format
$options = array(
    'options' => array(
        'default' => 3, // value to return if the filter fails
        // other options here
        'min_range' => 0
    ),
    'flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_OCTAL,
);
```

See: http://php.net/filter_var

So:

```
$c = 48;

if (filter_var($c, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array("options" => array("min_range"=>2,"max_range"=>15))) === false) {
    echo "bad";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

They should be in the options array:

```
if ( filter_var($c, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
        "options"=>array(
            "min_range"=>2,
            "max_range"=>15
        )
    )) === false ) {
    echo "bad";
}
```

Seems overly complicated way to write `2 <= $c && $c <= 15` though

Comment: Complicated - truly - some options seem more to be there to allow a full set of features, even if there is a simpler method for more minor tasks. This is really more useful as a filter where setting a variable to it has the added benefit of typecasting the result. There are easier ways (like typecasting it yourself) but this is one of the simplest options for filter_var, which has more impressive capabilities.